# How do existential types differ from interfaces?

Tags: java, interfaces, type-systems

Given the existential type

```
T = ∃X.{op₁:X, op₂:X→boolean}
```

and this generic Java interface:

```
interface T<X> {
    X op₁();
    boolean op₂(X something);
}
```

What are the fundamental differences between the existential type and the Java interface?

Obviously there are syntactical differences, and Java's object-orientation (which also includes details such as hidden `this` parameters etc.). I'm not so much interested in these as in conceptual and semantic differences — though if someone would like to shed light on some finer points (such as the notational difference between `T` vs. `T<X>`), that would be appreciated too.

Comment: http://blog.functorial.com/posts/2010-12-04-Existential-Types.html

Answer (score 5):

Hmm... That definition looks very similar to some haskell sample I've seen long time ago.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
data X = forall a . X { value :: a, viewValue :: a -> String }
instance Show X where show (X { value = x, viewValue = f}) = f x
sample :: [X]
sample = [X 3 show, X "abc" show, X 3.14 show]
```

When constructor `X` is applied ∀ actually becomes ∃. Note that when you take out `value` you don't know the type and have empty set of operation over it. But since `viewValue` is kinda coherent with `value` it can be applied to it.

I guess the main difference of Java `interface` you proposed is the fact that you have to know intermediate type for passing result of `op₁` to `op₂`. I.e. proper system for existential type should select the right type which is guaranteed to exist by condition. I.e. you should be able to write function with type: `∀X. X→(X→boolean)→T`. In prev sample such function is `X` constructor used in `X 3 show` (`show` is function which takes argument of any type that implements `Show` and returns `String`)

**Updated:** I just re-read your question and I think I've got proper construction for Java:

```java
interface T {
    boolean op₂();
}
...
T x = new T() {
    private final int op₁ = ...;
    public boolean op₂() { return ((op₁ % 2) == 0); }
};
T y = new T() {
    private final char op₁ = ...;
    public boolean op₂() { return ('0' <= op₁ && op₁ <= '9'); }
};
if (x.op₂() && y.op₂()) ...
```

You are right about mentioning `this` - it's actually your op₁.

So I guess I understood now that classical OOP languages (Java, C#, C++ etc) always implement existential type with single value `this` and a functions over it called "methods" which implicitly called with that value :)

P.S. Sorry, I'm not very familiar with Java, but I hope you've got the idea.

Comment: I'll add to this that you'll want to look at the Single Abstract Method (SAM) type that is being introduced in Java 8 for functional programming support.

Answer (score 3):

The 2 presented types are very different from each other. The interface definition you've written is an universal type (Java generics in general fall in this category).

An existential type hides a type within its implementation from the consumer. Intuitively, for X to be existential in T, X's identity cannot be known from any consumer; all that should be known is the set of operations provided at definition. There exists one type T for some type X.

In contrast, an universal type defines operations applicable to all types, from which the consumer is free to choose. The interface type T is exactly that. X is instantiated by the consumer, who'll know exactly which type X is. There exists a type T for every type X in the universe.

Existentials aren't actually present in Java as a language construct, except for in the limited case of wildcards (`List<?>`). But yes, they can be emulated with interfaces. The problem then becomes more of design.

As ony pointed out, in an object-oriented setting, existentials become tricky to implement because the way you usually encode the type information of X (what you can do with it) is to have member functions in an interface type which X implements. In short, interfaces can buy some type abstraction capabilities, but require the elimination of the existential to some extent.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is that the Java interface actually means something to the Java compiler.

The existential type is the *formal* definition of a type, non-specific to any language. Computer scientists use this sort of definition to prove things about the type and about languages implementing it.  The Java interface is one of Java's implementations of the formally defined type.

Comment: nope. cf william cook paper.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm years late, but this is a top Google result and these answers are all really confusing even though this question as posed has a really clear answer.

Consider the following two Java classes:

```java
abstract class IntT {
    int op1();
    boolean op2(int something);
}

abstract class StrT {
    String op1();
    boolean op2(String something);
}
```

Both `IntT` and `StrT` are subtypes of the existential type `T` you described, you can see that right?

Also, `IntT` satisfies the interface `T<int>`, and `StrT` satisfies the interface `T<String>`, you can see that right?

Those are two very different situations, because `T` is necessarily the same type as itself, whereas `T<int>` and `T<String>` are different types. That sounds like a stupidly obvious, but consider this: a `List<T>` can contain a mixture of `IntT`s and `StrT`s as elements, whereas a `List<T<int>>` can only contain `IntT`s, and a `List<T<String>>` can only contain `StrT`s:

```java
// preliminaries
IntT someIntT = ...
StrT someStrT = ...

// totally valid:
List<T> mixedList = new ArrayList<T>();
mixedList.add(someIntT);
mixedList.add(someStrT);

// whereas:
List<T<int>> intList = new ArrayList<T<int>>();
intList.add(someIntT); // cool
intList.add(someStrT); // not cool!! Invalid!

List<T<String>> strList = new ArrayList<T<String>>();
strList.add(someStrT); // cool
strList.add(someIntT); // not cool!! Invalid!
```

(A `List<T<Object>>` wouldn't be able to contain a mixture of `IntT`s and `StrT`s either, because the way the `T<X>` interface is defined is [invariant in `X`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8482091), so `T<int>` and `T<String>` are neither subtypes nor a supertypes of `T<Object>` and vice versa. They're just disjoint, unrelated types, like `int` and `String` are from each other.)

Comment: This is an incredibly lucid, well-written question—I was actually googling to find the answer to this question, and it was written so clearly that reading it helped me realize the answer. (I had just read and thought I understood [this more general question about existential types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5520212/362030), but then wondered "wait but how is this different from interfaces?")